# Swift Mac Os Application - NSSavePanel does not behave correctly with a 'background only' application

Tags: swift, macos, panel, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

I'm developing a swift Mac OS app that works only in the status bar (with a popover) with `Application is background only` set to `true`.

Inside the popover the user can interact with a button to save an image, more specifically the following function is triggered:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: NSButton) {
    self.closePopover()

    let dialog = NSSavePanel()

    let date = Date()
    let formattedDate = getFormattedDate(date: date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd")
    let formattedTime = getFormattedDate(date: date, format: "HH.mm.ss")
    dialog.level = .modalPanel
    dialog.title                    = "Choose a destination"
    dialog.nameFieldStringValue     = "Screenshot \(formattedDate) at \(formattedTime)"
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator     = true
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles         = false
    dialog.canCreateDirectories     = true
    dialog.allowedFileTypes         = ["png"]

    if (dialog.runModal() == .OK) {
        // Pathname of the file
        if let result = dialog.url {
            self.screenshot!.savePNGRepresentationToURL(url: result)
        }
    } else {
        // User clicked on "Cancel"
        return
    }
}
```

The problem is that:

- If I put `Application is background only` = `true`:
  I can't interact with the NSSavePanel (can't change the `save as` field) and if I write inside that box, the text is written in the last application I was interacting (the focus is not really on the modal).
- If I put `Application is background only` = `false`:
  the NSSavePanel works perfectly fine but that is not a good solution because I don't want to have the icon to appear in the dock

So the problem is clearly linked to the `Application is background only` but I didn't find a way to have both:

- no app icon in the dock
- good interaction with the NSSavePanel

Comment: You would probably need to launch another app. Take a look how Dropbox menu works. It is background only but sometimes it launches its app.

Comment: For dropbox "sync issue" section you are right. This could be a way to solve it.
I was looking for a way to programmatically turn off the is background only and then turn it on again after the selection has been done... But probably your suggestion is better.

Comment: Using `NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy` it worked, I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the `NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy` method like this:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: NSButton) {
    self.closePopover()

    NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.regular)

    let dialog = NSSavePanel()

    let date = Date()
    let formattedDate = getFormattedDate(date: date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd")
    let formattedTime = getFormattedDate(date: date, format: "HH.mm.ss")
    dialog.level = .modalPanel
    dialog.title                    = "Choose a destination"
    dialog.nameFieldStringValue     = "Screenshot \(formattedDate) at \(formattedTime)"
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator     = true
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles         = false
    dialog.canCreateDirectories     = true
    dialog.allowedFileTypes         = ["png"]

    if (dialog.runModal() == .OK) {
        // Pathname of the file
        if let result = dialog.url {
            self.screenshot!.savePNGRepresentationToURL(url: result)
        }
    } else {
        // User clicked on "Cancel"
    }

    NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
}
```